# How to join two 2D array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two 2D array and what to merge row VS row.

`arr1 = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`

`arr2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

I want to have output like this

`arr2 = [[a,b,c,1,2,3],[d,e,f,4,5,6],[g,h,i,7,8,9]]`

How do I do this with map method?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i'],
];

const arr2 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
];

const result = arr1.map((arr1Item, i) => [...arr1Item, ...arr2[i]]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` with `map`:

```js
var arr1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']];
var arr2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

var result = arr1.map((k,i)=>k.concat(arr2[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use map, map and push like so...

```js
const foo = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['d','e','f'],
    ['g','h','i']
]

const bar = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]

foo.map((el, i) => {
    el.map((e) => {
        bar[i].push(e)
    })
})

console.log(bar)
```